# What does ';' in start of this source code do?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use this script from github which is swipebox and my editor is pointing this out, the error says "***unnecessary semicolon shadowing of global property undefine***", which I presume is the semi-colon in the first line ';'

Here is the first line of code.

```
;( function ( window, document, $, undefined ) {
```